# Is it possible to import unmanaged class or struct from DLL using C# DllImport?

Tags: c#, c++, class, dll, dllimport

As msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx says "Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke) allows managed code to call unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL."

I want to import some class from DLL that i made in c++
Is it possible and how?

for example, i have some structures inside DLL:

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) DLLVector3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct __declspec(dllexport) DLLQuaternion
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) DLLCharacter
{
public:
    DLLVector3 position;
    DLLQuaternion orientation;

    DLLCharacter()
    {

    }

    ~DLLCharacter()
    {

    }

    void setPosition(PxVec3 pos)
    {
        position.x = pos.x;
        position.y = pos.y;
        position.z = pos.z;
    }

    void setOrientation(PxQuat or)
    {
        orientation.x = or.x;
        orientation.y = or.y;
        orientation.z = or.z;
        orientation.w = or.w;
    }
};

struct __declspec(dllexport) PhysicalObject
{
    DLLCharacter *character;
    PxRigidActor *mActor;
    PxController *mController;
};
```

Which way i can import those? Especially those structures with pointers

Comment: Why do you need this? You use .Net Questerion and Vector3 and define your class in C#

Comment: this is just an example of classes... i have DLL working with PhysX, that loading meshes, creating geometry and etc, but i still need to import some classed from this DLL to use them in .Net for tracing. Instead of making PhysX wrapper i better implement needed functional in DLL and import a lot less things from my DLL, instead of whole PhysX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to write C++ managed code for access - but - you can't easily hop around between unmanaged and managed memory.  Here's a few key points
1) Use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] to define .net classes that map on top of your c++ structs

> ```
> [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
> [Serializable]
> public struct SFVec3F : IRawStreamIO
> {
>     public double _x;
>     public double _y;
>     public double _z;
> }
> ```

2)  Basic types like doubles, int32, etc move across the P/Invoke layer efficiently - more complex types earn you the .net variant of thunking -  msft doco covers which data types move efficiently, try and use them

3)  Everything that's a pointer in C++ land is an IntPtr in .net land and if you want to be safe you should treat it as a handle, i.e. you get the c++ side to do any manipulations/access to the underlying structure

4) Access to the native C++ is pretty straightforward (the Handle props are IntPtrs that were originally sourced on the native C++ side)

```
[DllImport("CS2V3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void AddChild(IntPtr csoPtr, IntPtr childPtr, short recomputeBounds, short adjustCoords, short blindchild);
public void AddChild(V3CSO theChild)
{
    AddChild(m_handle, theChild.Handle,0,0,0);
}
```

5) Strings and some other types require marshalling to obtain a .net usable form - note that this happens automatically for strings when you pass a string to unmanaged code, but you have to do it yourself when it's inbound

```
 [DllImport("CS2V3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr GetName(IntPtr csoPtr);
[DllImport("CS2V3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void SetName(IntPtr csoPtr, string newName);
```

> ```
>    public string Name
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             IntPtr np = GetName(m_handle);
>             return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(np);
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             SetName(m_handle, value);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible.... but you need to write wrapper code in C++/CLI. This allows you to write classes that can be used from C#/.net code (on the outside it is managed code), and in the implementation you can use C++ code.

You can't import the C++ classes directly. Only C-style functions. C-style functions only allow you to pass C primitive types, which makes interopping with them easy. In general, from non-C++ code, it is close to impossible to correctly pass in C++ types. And if you can't pass in C++ objects, there are typically very few interesting functions  that you can call.

Later edit: 
Alternatively, you can write a C-style wrapper function for your unmanaged functionality. You will have to pass all parameters in one go (you can pass structs), but you can write the wrapper in standard C/C++.

Comment: what if i make a function inside DLL that return object pointer as void*, then from c# import that function and to set / read class members i use something like: (received_pointer + 4) = 2; //if struct inside dll was like struct weird_st {int a; int b;};?

Comment: You can but it sounds like a pain to maintain.